# Push notifications to the browser when some event happened in server side

Tags: java, servlets, comet

I am using a `Servlet` `ticketlist` which shows the list of tickets to the agent. 
I want to push a notification to the agent whenever a new ticket is assigned to him. 
New tickets are created by another webservice `assignTicket`. Now i want to notify the agent when a new ticket is assigned to him.

Currently i do not have any idea on how to achieve this requirement. Is it possible to trigger an event from `assignTicket` webservice to `ticketlist` `servlet` so that the `servlet` will notify the agent?

Comment: google for websockets, polling, server-sent events

Comment: I've used [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/) for this.  For reference, I don't work for PubNub.

Comment: Simple with PubNub: your agents subscribe to a channel that is uniquely named for them. Your web service just publishes a message to the assigned agents channel. It should take no more than 30 minutes to implement a POC for this use case.